# Database return value gets changed

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am making a loginscreen and want to compare the values with the saved values in my database. For security reasons I have hashed the saved passwords so that they can not be read.

the problem I run in to is that the return from the database is not the same as the saved value in the database.

Saved value `??\u0013)??V\a!?=:???\u0016x\u0013??`

Return value `??\\u0013)??V\\a!?=:???\\u0016x\\u0013??`

as you can see the slash is doubled in the return string.

My question is the following: where does the code double the slashes and how can I stop this?

thank you in advance for your help!

```
    private Tuple<bool, string> AskPassword(int zone)
            {
                PendingOrdersReadTableAdapters.PersoneelTableAdapter personeelTableAdapter = new PendingOrdersReadTableAdapters.PersoneelTableAdapter() { Connection = { ConnectionString = CppImport.returnConnectionString() } };
                DataTable myData;

                UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();
                Start:
                // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
                if (userLogin.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string username = userLogin.getUser();
                    //get the data connected to this username
                    myData = personeelTableAdapter.GetByName(username);
                    int userSalt = Convert.ToInt32(myData.Rows[0]["Salt"]);

                    Password pwd = new Password(userLogin.getPassword(), userSalt);
                    // UsergivenPassword is ??\u0013)??V\a!?=:???\u0016x\u0013?? 
                    string userGivenPassword = pwd.ComputeSaltedHash();
                    // savedPassword is ??\\u0013)??V\\a!?=:???\\u0016x\\u0013?? 
                    var savedPassword = myData.Rows[0]["SaltedHash"];
                    if (userGivenPassword == savedPassword ) { return Tuple.Create(true, username); }
                    else { MessageBox.Show("Wachtwoord niet correct"); goto Start; }

                }
                else
                {
                    userLogin.Dispose();
                    return Tuple.Create(false,string.Empty);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the returned value is a string.
In many systems the `'\'` character denotes a command character follows e.g. `"\n"` for newline.

To have a `'\'` character to display in a string you'd place `"\\"` in the string.
I suspect that your database field is a string, hence it is adding an additional `'\'` character so that your Unicode character code that follows is correctly displayed.

Two points spring to mind:

1. Are you sure that you're storing a hashed password?
2. Normally you compare the hashed/encrypted password values, without any back conversion.

**edit**

You're right, having checked, Access doesn't appear to allow you to store a binary field. The hashed password would be binary, could there be an issue with the storage of the password e.g. Access automatically adding in the `'\'` character on writing the field?

Try converting the hashed password into a string representation of hex e.g. 320A4F..., before storage. You could then compare that string rather than the hashed value.

`SoapHexBinary` class might help you there.

Comment: it is indeed saved as a string in an Access database (Short text field). I do not think there is an option to save it in a different way in the database. There is also no back conversion I do however make a hash code from the user given password.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, the problem is not in the access database. As soon as I import it in the code it doubles the slashes (as you explained). But by implementing you idea  of converting the string to hex I can now save, load and compare it without problems thank you!